# El ejecutable de Netbeans no abre en otras maquinas

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jar

actualmente presento un problema. Y como dice el titulo tiene que ver con el ejecutable de Java con Netbeans, mi problema viene en que estoy haciendo un programa con sockets y estoy intentando probarlo con otras maquinas ajenas a la mia, el problema viene en que cuando quiero ejecutar el programa, dicho programa no abre, instale la misma version de jdk y jre y no sucede nada, mas bien lo unico que llega a abrir es el joptionpane pero poco mas, nose si tiene que ver algo con la interfaz grafica o con que realmente

```html
public Cliente() {
        String nick_usuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nick: ");

        initComponents();

        JNickname.setText(nick_usuario);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        EnviaTexto mievento = new EnviaTexto();

        Conectar_ClienteBtn.addActionListener(mievento);

        Thread host = new Thread(this);

        host.start();

        addWindowListener(new EnvioOnline());
    }
```

Es mas, siendo mas especifico, pareciera que todo lo que viene despues del "initComponents" no funcionara, porque incluso he intentado correr el programa con el JOptionPane despues del "init" y de esa manera no abre nada. Nose a que se deba este problema (tambien aclarar que el formato con el que creo el ejecutable es el mismo jdk que tengo instalado el jdk8)

Comment: [Habilita la consola de Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.html) en el cliente y compártenos el mensaje de error.

Comment: Dice "exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout"

Comment: En las Propiedades del Proyecto, en *Libraries* ¿Tienes AbsoluteLayout? y en *Build > Packaging* ¿tienes seleccionado *Copy Dependant Libraries*? ¿Probaste haciendo *Clean And Build* antes de crear el jar?

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, el problema es que tenia que exportar el programa con una carpeta donde tuviera el path hacia el AbsoluteLayout